# Printing multiple files in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, printjs

I have multiple blobs from which i am creating blob urls and using [print-js](https://printjs.crabbly.com/) library to show print preview screen of browser.

I have

```
async printDocuments(): Promise<any> {
    const _files: { fileName: string, blob: any }[] = await this._getFiles();
    _files.forEach((_fileInfo, index) => {
        const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(_fileInfo.blob);
        printJS(blobUrl);
    });
}
```

but this shows print preview dialog for just first file.

How can I print all the documents either by merging or opening multiple printing windows.

I tried using this

```
printJS({
    printable: _files[0].blob,
    type: "pdf",
    onPrintDialogClose: () => {
      console.log("nex");
    }
});
```

but now it is showing

```
core.js:4196 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: params.printable.charAt is not a function
TypeError: params.printable.charAt is not a function
```

Comment: Try using the library `onPrintDialogClose` and only trigger the next print job once the first one it's done. The browser may be ignoring the other jobs since they are being triggered before the first one is processed.
https://printjs.crabbly.com/#configuration

Comment: @crabbly, updated the question, can you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onPrintDialogClose` worked for me.

Here is what I did

```
async printDocuments(): Promise<any> {
     const _files: { fileName: string, blob: any }[] = await this._getFiles();
     if (_files && _files.length > 0) {
            this._printDocument(_files, 0);
     }
}

private _printDocument(files: { fileName: string, blob: any }[], index: number): void {
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(files[index].blob);
    printJS({
        printable: blobUrl,
        type: "pdf",
        onPrintDialogClose: () => {
            index = index + 1;
            if (index < files.length) {
                this._printDocument(files, index);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the [documentation](https://printjs.crabbly.com/#configuration)

Thanks to @crabbly

**Edit** - Latest chrome does not work with callback

With the latest chrome, `onPrintDialogClose` is not working. For this remove the `onPrintDialogClose` from printJs call and add the following code after `printJs` call.

```
// fix : printjs issue #495
const handler = () => {
    // Make sure the event only happens once.
    window.removeEventListener("mouseover", handler);

    // function that you want to execute for onPrintDialogClose
    onCloseCallback();

    // Remove iframe from the DOM, by default 'printJS'
    const iframe = document.getElementById("printJS");

    if (iframe) {
        iframe.remove();
    }
    };
setTimeout(() => { window.addEventListener("mouseover", handler); }, 1000);
```